# .htaccess caused slowness of loading admin folder?

Tags: php, apache, performance, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Alright, I'm using this simple .htacess to redirect all requests that are not folders or files to index.php.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Everything on the user-facing side works great. However, I have a separate admin folder, which contains it's own index.php. The .htaccess there does allow the folder to load and display it's index.php file, but it takes lightyears of time to do so. Could this slowness be caused of the .htaccess? Or what about the fact that the admin folder loads styles, assets and such from the server root, thus everything passes trough .htaccess again?

Comment: Use the developer tools available in all major browsers. Look into the network tab to see which resource is taking time to load or check if any script is caught in a loop

Comment: .htaccess works really fast normally. Try to disable it and see if your admin folder will deliver your data faster.

Comment: @Antony Did that, to me, it seemed like it was the /admin/ itself...

Comment: @Antony also, here's a puush of the network tab of devtools: http://puu.sh/mlXOR/ffe9e1da75.png

Comment: If its not faster wiith disabled htacces then the problem is probanly the php code.

Comment: @maxhb Mopre likely just xampp being slow.. on an actual server, loads just fine. Phew. crysis averted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAMPP does this on local connections. God knows why.